# why gets my data lost / possible problem with pointers

Tags: c

i'm trying to adapt the example code from this site https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/making-a-queue-using-linked-list-in-c/

but i can't get it to work properly, when changing the node datatype to somesting "more complex"
thought it would be simple but when i call display it outputs all "0"

```c
// #include "include/main.h"
#include <time.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define QUEUE_SIZE 30

typedef float dataArray[20];

struct node
{
    dataArray *data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;

struct queue
{
    int count;
    node *front;
    node *rear;
};
typedef struct queue queue;

void initialize(queue *q);
int is_empty(queue *q);
void enqueue(queue *q, dataArray value);
void dequeue(queue *q, dataArray *outputArray);
void display(node *head);

float random_float();

void initialize(queue *q)
{
    q->count = 0;
    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear = NULL;
}

int is_empty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->rear == NULL);
}

void enqueue(queue *q, dataArray value)
{
    if (q->count == QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
        dataArray tmp;
        dequeue(q, &tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
    node *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("[enqueue] sizeof node %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(node));
    // memcpy(tmp->data, value, sizeof(value));
    tmp->data = &value;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    
    printf(" contents of value in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", value[i]);
    }

    printf(" contents of tmp-node in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", tmp->data[i]);
    }

    if (!is_empty(q))
    {
        q->rear->next = tmp;
        q->rear = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        q->front = q->rear = tmp;
    }
    q->count++;
}

void dequeue(queue *q, dataArray *outputArray)
{
    node *tmp;
    outputArray = q->front->data;
    printf("dequeue output before freeing memory\r\n===========\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", outputArray[i]);
    }
    printf("[dequeue] size %d - %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(q->front->data), (uint) sizeof(q->front->data[0]));
    tmp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->next;
    q->count--;
    free(tmp);
}

void display(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            printf("%f\n", head->data[i]);
        }

        display(head->next);
    }
}

float random_float()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    float a = 50.0;
    return ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
}

int main()
{
    queue *q;
    q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    initialize(q);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    dataArray tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = random_float();
    }
    printf("display dataArray before fill\r\n===========\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", tmp[i]);
    }

    enqueue(q, tmp);
    
    printf("Queue display after init and fill\r\n===========\r\n");
// THIS WILL PRINT 0 <<<<--------------------------------------- what it shouldn't
    display(q->front);

    printf("Queue before dequeue\r\n===========\r\n");
    printf("Queue #1  element count: %d\r\n", q->count);
    // Nächsten Queue Eintrag holen
    dataArray *queData = malloc(sizeof(dataArray));
    dequeue(q, queData);
    printf("Queue after dequeue\r\n===========\r\n");
    printf("Queue #1  element count: %d\r\n", q->count);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", queData[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

(also first i wanted to give enqueue the pointer of my temp-array so it don't has to copy it but that worked even worse)

EDIT
this is the version where i'm passing the pointer of the array to enqueue, but in this version even within enqueue the output is not correct (only for the first value of the array)

```c
// #include "include/main.h"
#include <time.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define QUEUE_SIZE 30

typedef float dataArray[20];

struct node
{
    dataArray *data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;

struct queue
{
    int count;
    node *front;
    node *rear;
};
typedef struct queue queue;

void initialize(queue *q);
int is_empty(queue *q);
void enqueue(queue *q, dataArray *value);
void dequeue(queue *q, dataArray *outputArray);
void display(node *head);

float random_float();

void initialize(queue *q)
{
    q->count = 0;
    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear = NULL;
}

int is_empty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->rear == NULL);
}

void enqueue(queue *q, dataArray *value)
{
    if (q->count == QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
        dataArray tmp;
        dequeue(q, &tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
    
    printf(" contents of value in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", *value[i]);
    }
    
    node *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("[enqueue] sizeof node %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(node));
    // memcpy(tmp->data, &value, sizeof(value));
    tmp->data = value;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    


    printf(" contents of tmp-node in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", tmp->data[i]);
    }

    if (!is_empty(q))
    {
        q->rear->next = tmp;
        q->rear = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        q->front = q->rear = tmp;
    }
    q->count++;
}

void dequeue(queue *q, dataArray *outputArray)
{
    node *tmp;
    outputArray = q->front->data;
    printf("dequeue output before freeing memory\r\n===========\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", outputArray[i]);
    }
    printf("[dequeue] size %d - %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(q->front->data), (uint) sizeof(q->front->data[0]));
    tmp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->next;
    q->count--;
    free(tmp);
}

void display(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            printf("%f\n", head->data[i]);
        }

        display(head->next);
    }
}

float random_float()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    float a = 50.0;
    return ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
}

int main()
{
    queue *q;
    q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    initialize(q);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    dataArray tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = random_float();
    }
    printf("display dataArray before fill\r\n===========\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", tmp[i]);
    }

    enqueue(q, &tmp);
    
    printf("Queue display after init and fill\r\n===========\r\n");
    display(q->front);

    printf("Queue before dequeue\r\n===========\r\n");
    printf("Queue #1  element count: %d\r\n", q->count);
    // Nächsten Queue Eintrag holen
    dataArray *queData = malloc(sizeof(dataArray));
    dequeue(q, queData);
    printf("Queue after dequeue\r\n===========\r\n");
    printf("Queue #1  element count: %d\r\n", q->count);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", queData[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: Don't use a `typedef` for an array.  You're just going to confuse yourself.  If you try to pass an array as a function argument, you are in fact passing its address.  Don't hide that in a `typedef`.

Comment: Every node needs to have its own data object, allocated with `malloc`.  Don't think that you can be clever and just point to an object that already exists.  It won't work.  Either you will point to an object whose lifetime expires and leaves your pointer dangling, or you end up with many pointers to the same object and a change to one will affect all.

Comment: ok ... so if i pass in the array as a pointer, and try printf("%f\n", *value[i]);, first value will be good, rest is trash... as you can see i already experimented with mallox, but it always results in segmentation fault. i'm aware of that i have to free objects once they have dequeued, but .. so you say the whole concept is "wrong"?

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to store a pointer in the queue, and to manage the storage for the data it points to with `malloc` and `free`.  So if the data is an array, you allocate a data array with `malloc`, and store a pointer to that data in your queue.  When deleting an element, you need to free the data pointer.

Comment: Using a [linked list to create a queue in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-linked-list-implementation/).

Comment: that was my original intention, but if i pass the pointer to the array (to store the pointer in node->data), as i wrote above `printf("%f\n", *value[i])` will only print the correct value for the first item, i will update the code in the original post to show

Comment: @ryyker thats basicly the same code, all i want to achieve is to replace the int-value with an array

Comment: Does it have to be a pointer member?  Why not just use an array member? (i.e. `double dataArray[20];` )  Unless you do not know the size requirement until run-time, you will save complexity and time by not using something you need to allocate and free memory for.  At least start it that way, get it working, then expand it as needed.   Walk, then run.

Comment: hmm good idea, also an int[20] would be enough since at the end i will need 4 digits that i can divide through 10 - i will do so, but it would be really great to understand what the problem is and what i'm doing wrong (and will using an array of int solve my problem? i will try)

Comment: seems not to solve my problem, also tried again with memcpy but still segmentation fault (tried different methods for sizeof)

Comment: ok now i know again why i wanted to handle the pointers instead of the array, i can't assign a new array to an existing array, so i have to replace the pointer afaik, so this will not solve the problem :(

Comment: the only "solution" that came to my mind would be to ass as much data-properties to the struct as i have array-elements, but that can't be the solution?

Comment: No matter what the type of `value` is,  `tmp->data = &value;` (in `enqueue`) is bound to be wrong.  `value` is a local parameter.  Its address is meaningless after the function returns.

Comment: yes that would explain why the first example won't work, but the second SHOULD i think, but doesn't

Comment: @mech don’t add solutions into the question

Comment: @user438383 but how could others see the result?

Comment: @mech they can look at the answers. that's how SO works. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387912/can-should-i-edit-my-question-to-an-add-answer

Comment: of course, but the answer is not comlpete, it is a good guide and i thought 1. it could be interesting for the one who answered what i did with his answer and 2. others that may have a similar problem can see the (mostly) final result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"yes that would explain why the first example won't work, but the second SHOULD"* -- No, no it won't.

First, enable Full Warnings in your compiler<sup>1</sup>. Now try and compile your second example. Notice the problems in all of your attempted `printf()` statements where `%f` expects a `double` arguments, but you are passing `float *` (a pointer to float). Why aren't there more descriptive errors? What do the comments under your question say to remove? (hint: your `typedef` is masking errors)

So go to your second example and comment the `typedef`, e.g.

```c
// typedef float dataArray[20];
```

Why was that causing problems? Look at your parameters, e.g.

```c
void enqueue(queue *q, dataArray *value) { ...
```

What is your `dataArray *value`? It's `float *value[20];` What's that? It is `float *[20]`, an array of `20` *pointers* to `float`. When you assign `tmp->data = value;` what are you assigning? [C18 - 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2) tells you. `value` is converted to a pointer to it's first element (a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `float`, e.g. `float**`). What is `tmp->data`? It is an *array of pointers to* `float` and it is not an lvalue -- see [6.3.2.1(p1)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2). You cannot assign to an array, but your typedef is masking the problem.

Now remove your `typedef` (throughout your code) and try again, e.g.:

```c
void enqueue(queue *q, float *value[20])
{
    if (q->count == QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
        float tmp[20];
        dequeue(q, &tmp);
        // free(tmp);         /* you can't free what's not allocated */
    }
    
    printf(" contents of value in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", *value[i]);
    }
    
    node *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("[enqueue] sizeof node %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(node));
    // memcpy(tmp->data, &value, sizeof(value));
    tmp->data = value;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    ...
```

(you had `memcpy()`, you were closer there but your types are messed up)

It doesn't work. Now the compiler easily sees the attempt to assign to a non-lvalue and provides a proper diagnostic:

```
source.c:65:15: error: assignment to expression with array type
     tmp->data = value;
               ^
```

That problem runs throughout your code. Where does the mismatch begin? In `main()`. Look at what you are trying to pass to `enqueue()`, e.g.

```c
int main()
{
    ...
    dataArray tmp;        /* e.g. float tmp[20] */
    ...
    enqueue(q, &tmp);
    ...
}
```

When you take the address of `tmp` the type is `float (*)[20]`, a *pointer-to-array-of* `float[20]`, not an *array-of-pointers-to* `float` (20 of them). A *pointer-to-array* has type `float (*)[20]` while the array-of-pointers* is `float *[20]` -- completely different types and pointer arithmetic is completely different between the two.

So when you pass `&tmp` with `enqueue(q, &tmp);` (where `tmp` is passed as `value` to `void enqueue(queue *q, dataArray *value)`) and then do `value[i]` in your first loop, for values of `i > 0`, you invoke undefined behavior reading beyond the end of the array (passed as a *pointer-to-array*, `value[1]` is one past the end of your array `tmp` in `main()` of `float[20]`)

**Can You Make It Work?**

Yes, just fix the types and remove the second call to `srand()` in `random_float()` that is messing up your fill and fix your `memcpy()` call. (there are numerous other small issues, memory not validated and memory not freed, etc..) Carrying the removal of your `typedef` through the rest of your code and making the types consistent, you would end up with something like:

```c
#include <time.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define QUEUE_SIZE 30
#define ASZ 20

// typedef float dataArray[20];
typedef unsigned uint;

struct node
{
    float data[ASZ];
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;

struct queue
{
    int count;
    node *front;
    node *rear;
};
typedef struct queue queue;

void initialize(queue *q);
int is_empty(queue *q);
void enqueue(queue *q, float *value);
void dequeue(queue *q, float *outputArray);
void display(node *head);

float random_float();

void initialize(queue *q)
{
    q->count = 0;
    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear = NULL;
}

int is_empty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->rear == NULL);
}

void enqueue(queue *q, float *value)
{
    if (q->count == QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
        float tmp[ASZ];
        dequeue(q, tmp);
        // free(tmp);
    }
    
    printf(" contents of value in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", value[i]);
    }
    
    node *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("[enqueue] sizeof node %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(node));
    // memcpy(tmp->data, &value, sizeof(value));
    memcpy (tmp->data, value, ASZ * sizeof *value);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    
    printf(" contents of tmp-node in enqueue\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", tmp->data[i]);
    }

    if (!is_empty(q))
    {
        q->rear->next = tmp;
        q->rear = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        q->front = q->rear = tmp;
    }
    q->count++;
}

void dequeue(queue *q, float *outputArray)
{
    node *tmp;
    outputArray = q->front->data;
    printf("dequeue output before freeing memory\r\n===========\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", outputArray[i]);
    }
    printf("[dequeue] size %d - %d\r\n", (uint) sizeof(q->front->data), 
            (uint) sizeof(q->front->data[0]));
    tmp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->next;
    q->count--;
    free(tmp);
}

void display(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
        {
            printf("%f\n", head->data[i]);
        }

        display(head->next);
    }
}

float random_float()
{
    float a = 50.0;
    return ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
}

int main()
{
    queue *q;
    q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    initialize(q);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    float tmp[ASZ];
    for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = random_float();
    }
    printf("display dataArray before fill\r\n===========\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", tmp[i]);
    }

    enqueue(q, tmp);
    
    printf("Queue display after init and fill\r\n===========\r\n");
    display(q->front);

    printf("Queue before dequeue\r\n===========\r\n");
    printf("Queue #1  element count: %d\r\n", q->count);
    // Nächsten Queue Eintrag holen
    float *queData = malloc(sizeof(float[ASZ]));
    dequeue(q, queData);
    printf("Queue after dequeue\r\n===========\r\n");
    printf("Queue #1  element count: %d\r\n", q->count);

    for (int i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", queData[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Now your second example compiles without warning and, to the extent the logic is correct, produces reasonable output (whether it is correct is left to you to determine), e.g.

```
$ ./bin/llqueue
display dataArray before fill
===========
5.864568
15.599927
1.622677
6.834927
18.953743
43.170605
37.056793
21.260620
44.568668
41.187069
43.298340
8.273252
13.328741
33.927246
32.561504
14.666824
20.176983
30.163134
21.064775
8.606315
 contents of value in enqueue
5.864568
15.599927
1.622677
6.834927
18.953743
43.170605
37.056793
21.260620
44.568668
41.187069
43.298340
8.273252
13.328741
33.927246
32.561504
14.666824
20.176983
30.163134
21.064775
8.606315
[enqueue] sizeof node 88
 contents of tmp-node in enqueue
5.864568
15.599927
1.622677
6.834927
18.953743
43.170605
37.056793
21.260620
44.568668
41.187069
43.298340
8.273252
13.328741
33.927246
32.561504
14.666824
20.176983
30.163134
21.064775
8.606315
Queue display after init and fill
===========
5.864568
15.599927
1.622677
6.834927
18.953743
43.170605
37.056793
21.260620
44.568668
41.187069
43.298340
8.273252
13.328741
33.927246
32.561504
14.666824
20.176983
30.163134
21.064775
8.606315
NULL
Queue before dequeue
===========
Queue #1  element count: 1
dequeue output before freeing memory
===========
5.864568
15.599927
1.622677
6.834927
18.953743
43.170605
37.056793
21.260620
44.568668
41.187069
43.298340
8.273252
13.328741
33.927246
32.561504
14.666824
20.176983
30.163134
21.064775
8.606315
[dequeue] size 80 - 4
Queue after dequeue
===========
Queue #1  element count: 0
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
-0.001425
```

**Note:** this isn't an effort to correct ALL of the issues with your code. This merely gets you back on track from your `typedef` fiasco. While there are times where typedef'ing arrays makes sense (for experienced kernel developers, etc..), it's not something to do lightly for the reasons explained below. Pointers should not be typedef'ed either. See [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

**footnotes:**

1. Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). Turn on `-Werror` to treat all warnings as errors. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. The warnings will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: that was really helpful, thanks, i update my original post with the (temporary) result of your answer

Comment: edited my post but user438383 always reverts the changes, wanted to show the actual result, but ...

Comment: @mech - you can always edit and ADD a new version below your current text, but don't change the original question or text. Why? Because all comments and answers that came before you change the original no longer make sense. So just add the new version below. You can put **Edit** and then put the new version below that. That should not get reverted. You can also just paste it in [paste openSUSE](https://paste.opensuse.org/) and drop the link here. Or use [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) and just paste the share link in a comment.